# ASCII ³ displays as 3 in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plot and I need to add mm³ but I can't use bquote because I need to wrap the text using

```
paste(strwrap(text, width), collapse="\n")
```

so I though that I use ASCII ³ character bcause that's the only superscript value I need, but it display as mm3 when rendered, is it the font issue? How to resolve it? I need to run this on any platform becuase other developers use Mac/Windows, I use windows and it run Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Details on how to render mathematics in plots and elsewhere in R are documented in `?plotmath`.

A simple example, plotting the city gas millage by engine squared engine displacement.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg) +
  aes(x = displ^2, y = cty) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab(expression(displ^2)) +
  ylab("City Miles Per Gallon")
```

[image]

Comment: I've already resolved the issue, I was able to remove the part that didn't play nice with build in math characters in ggplot, but I was not able run normal expression to get super script, so the workaround was to use ASCII character that was not working. The answer is confusing because the question was about ASCII character not about super script in general.